# iOS Bug: Storyboard ID appearing as iOS back button text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a lot of navigation bar back buttons in my project with a single space as its text (" "), in order to prevent iOS from showing "Back". However, sometimes XCode will replace the back button text with a Storyboard ID plus ".text" for no apparent reason.

[Navigation Bar Back Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agZr0.png)

[Storyboard file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou1vg.png)

I have noticed that this problem often disappears when I rebuild the app, but this time it appeared after I archived my project, thus causing me some trouble...

Is this a bug with XCode's Interface Builder? Is there a way to fix that? I also have a localized version of the Storyboard, is that what is causing this problem?

XCode 7.2 (7C68)

iOS 9.2.1

**EDIT**

I have just changed the language of my iPhone and this bug disappeared, it is definitely related to the way XCode handles the localized version of the Storyboard.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your own problem. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Also, please submit a `radar`.

Comment: Actually I haven't solved it, I'm just pointing out that this might be a problem related to the localized version of the Storyboard (since the bug does not appear when you use another language), but I don't know what is causing this.